# Twitter Fabric 403 Forbidden

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I build an Ionic 3 app and i want to login with twitter.

So i installed the native twitter plugin.

I follow the guide(create twitter app, create account on Fabric, download fabric app...etc).

Everything works fine until yesterday where i was starting to get a response of 403 Forbidden Error. The twitter popup dialog didn't open anymore.

**UPDATE:**

ok manage to display a more declarative error message:

```
NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Twitter API error : <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><errors><error code=\"415\">Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings</error></errors> (code (null))";
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to go to Twitter app settings to approve the callback url that you used in the application. It’s not allowing because where you are returning to isn’t permitted in your twitter settings

Answer (score 0):

The key is to put twittersdk:// in the callback url

Answer (score 0):

Possible Fixes:

1- Add **callback url**. (if you don't have any Add **twittersdk://**)

2- Add **App usage** of your application at https://developer.twitter.com/